# How to add a hortizontal scroll in ApexCharts vue js

Tags: vue.js, scroll, apexcharts

[image]So, I am using **apexcharts in vue js** to show the data of **22 days in bar-chart**. Now, the problem is, all the bars are rendered together on screen and it looks like this(the graph above). I do not want that, What I want is, maybe show the first **10 day's bars** and show a button at the bottom where I can click and **scroll** a bit to the right and see the next 5 bars and scroll back by clicking another button next to it. I have been looking for it and I could not find it in the docs and googling it didn't help too. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I did notice that there is zoom and pan buttons in toolbar but I would like to render it auto zoomed at the left side and instead of panning, it should scroll when I click a button like I mentioned above.

Note: Is another open source charts library that has this feature built in?